# how to find cause for "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, debugging, firebug

This is the error I get:

[image]

The line in question in the un-minified jQuery 1.7.2 javascript file:

```
 error: function( msg ) {
     throw new Error( msg );
 },
```

From this, there is no way to figure out where the error is (or at least it isn't clear to me). I found that uncommenting this line from a jQuery plugin (http://shama.github.com/jmpress.js/#/docs) causes the error to stop:

```
$("#my_div").jmpress();
```

but I can't get greater granularity than that. Any debugging tips to help me find out where this JSON parsing is happening?

=== **EDIT:** ===

using JSON.parse, I was able to track down this particular string that was attempting to be parsed as a string:

```
_FB_f3757ad5f032398xd_action=proxy_ready&data
```

but can't nail down where it is coming into my code, but from the "*FB*" prefix it seems as though this string is part of the Facebook JS SDK (which I am using)

Comment: @RobW: To elaborate: `(function(){var _jp = JSON.parse; JSON.parse=function(a){console.log(a);return _jp.call(JSON,a)}}())`.  This will `console.log` the JSON attempting to be parsed.

Comment: Try to validate your JSON: http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Do you have any idea where this JSON is coming from?

Comment: @Rocket - this is great! I found some bad JSON with this. but I have no idea where it is being parsed / where I can find the in point for the JSON parsing in code...any hints how to do that?

Comment: It's not the parsing you need to worry about. The parsing is flawless. It's the JSON you are feeding it that you need to fix.

Comment: @Esailija - yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @Rocket the problem has to be tied to Facebook - that's where the \_FB\_ is coming from. but there is no facebook code in the jmpress plugin, which is strange

Comment: @RobW - where do you feed the function (function(){var _jp = JSON.parse; JSON.parse=function(a){console.log(a);return _jp.call(JSON,a)}}()) the JSON? I would presume you would supply the JSON, in place of "JSON" in _jp.call(JSON,a), however JSON has the same name as the function. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user66001 That line of code itself does not parse anything. After running that piece of code, calls to `JSON.parse` are logged in the console without breaking existing code.

Comment: @RobW Thanks, understand now. Have tried it, and all it prints is what I can get from catch(err), is there a way of finding what part of the JSON it cannot parse (Line no, for instance)?

Comment: @user66001 You can throw a `debugger;` statement inside. Then, when the (Chrome) dev tools are opened, you can inspect the call trace, inspect local/closure/global variables, and also see the exact location of the code. Another option is to put in `console.trace();`

Comment: @RobW - Thanks. Found out the JSON is sometimes being delivered with <pre> tags, which don't show when loading the page of JSON, and View Source seems to not be available despite the fact there seems to be markup that is being parsed! (Otherwise I would have alert'd the JSON! :( )... Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looking at the source code of jmpress it comes from the cross-origin iframe messaging. Basically jmpress [does this](https://github.com/shama/jmpress.js/blob/master/src/plugins/presentation-mode.js#L33):

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // We do not test orgin, because we want to accept messages
    // from all orgins
    try {
        var json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        switch(json.type) {
        case "select":
            // TODO SECURITY filter targetId
            $.each(eventData.settings.presentationMode.transferredValues, function(idx, name) {
                eventData.current[name] = json[name];
            });
            $(eventData.jmpress).jmpress("select", {step: "#"+json.targetId, substep: json.substep}, json.reason);
            break;
        case "listen":
            current.selectMessageListeners.push(event.source);
            break;
        case "ok":
            clearTimeout(current.presentationPopupTimeout);
            break;
        case "read":
            try {
                event.source.postMessage(JSON.stringify({type: "url", url: window.location.href, notesUrl: eventData.settings.presentationMode.notesUrl}), "*");
            } catch(e) {
                $.error("Cannot post message to source: " + e);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw "Unknown message type: " + json.type;
        }
    } catch(e) {
        $.error("Recieved message is malformed: " + e);
    }
});
```

So all iframes that post to the main window, will go through this event handler and log the error when they pass invalid JSON. It looks like you have a facebook iframe on your website, that posts messages to the main window. Try removing all of those and see if the errors disappear.

Comment: yup! removing the Facebook SDK does stop the errors...unfortunately also breaks my site in other ways haha. is there any way I can make these two thing play nice together? perhaps I could just make `jmpress` silently ignore bad JSON? (idk why Facebook thinks it's OK to pass around invalid JSON anyway...)

Comment: @lol: You can send whatever message you want between the frame and the window.  It does not  have to be JSON.  The problem is jmpress (wrongly) assumes that it should be JSON.

Comment: @lol It's not that facebook tries to even pass JSON. it's that jmpress makes a catch-all message handler that thinks everything is JSON. As the code comment says, it doesn't discriminate between iframe origins, it just takes anything.

Comment: @lol you can edit the jmpress source code not to throw an error and just silently fail. Remove this line `$.error("Recieved message is malformed: " + e);`

Comment: @lol: Does the error break the page?  Maybe you can just ignore it :-P

Comment: yes I see your points. I feel safe just commenting out that `$.error` throwing line. everything functions fine after that. one last thing - what are javascript messages? i'd like to learn more about them

Comment: @lol it's a safe way for 2 frames from different origins to communicate with each other on a page. Normally 2 frames from different origins cannot do anything to each other because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). With iframe messaging, both parties can implement the messaging API as a safe way to communicate with each other. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: @Esailija very cool. any thoughts on why `jmpress` would need cross origin communication? since it's a github plugin it isn't as though it is running content from another server, is it? it's just a slide presentation emulator..

Comment: @lol I am sure they have their reasons for requiring cross origin iframe communication but I'm not familiar with the plugin at all and it is not immediately apparent from reading their docs.